# How do I define a Windows file path as a variable?

Tags: perl, scripting

I am screwing around with a tiny script I am making and one thing I am trying to figure out is how to make a perl variable reflect an executable, for example.

```
$putty = C:\putty.exe;
```

When ever I run it like this it tells me "C:\ is not recognizable command, what am I doing wrong? I have also tried surrounding it in quotes and no help by that.

Comment: best solution is you don't ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be quoting literal strings, for example like

```
my $putty = 'C:\putty.exe';
```

If this is news to you, you might have been missing out on the `strict` pragma before. I highly recommend having a look at that and using it in all of your code.

Comment: Awesome that worked, now if I can get the thing to diplay the @ when not pretaining to an array and also it wont display IP addresses.